# OCX and the MVP Pattern in Window Forms (Winform)

Tags: winforms, mvp, ocx

Is there a way to detach the OCX from the UI (the Form class in Winforms, in this example)

I am trying to design the project using the MVP pattern

and hopefully use the OCX control in the Repository layer only and not in the UI.

Thanks in advance.

The best solution I came up with is a creating a ApiUtil class that encapsulates the control,

but inevitably, the UI has to have dependency of the Control regardless.